# How can i make sure middleware is run before another

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

Hi have a middleware that i must ensure is run after the auth middleware. How can i guarantee that the auth middleware is processed before mine? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the laravel 5.4 documentation:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
})->middleware('first', 'second');
```

First and second must be route middleware, if you look in app/Http/Kernel.php you can find them.

Comment: Will this also work in the controllers' `__construct()` with calls to `$this->middleware()`?

Comment: If you use multiple call to `$this->middleware()` in the controller `__construct()` method they should be called in the same order. I am not really sure but you can try by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Your middlware will be run after, Auth middleware have a higher priority. See variable $middlewarePriority of your Kernel base class (Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel).

First middleware is StartSession and this is what we want.

If you want, you can modify this variable to run one of your middleware before Auth.